# Разбиение малоцветного изображения на сплошные не смешивающиеся слои

Tags: c#, алгоритм, изображения

Я понял что нужно использовать Bitmap,в принципе я знаю как разрезать на куски, но вот как на слои понять не могу, я не прошу сделать всё за меня. Мне нужна только информация по моей теме, заранее благодарен. Может есть у кого нибудь подобные статьи или вы решали подобные задачи.

Comment: А что вы называете «слоем»?

Comment: По заданию получается что нужно разбить на одноцветные слои, как я понимаю нужно все цвета в растровом изображении считать отдельным слоем

Comment: Правильная постановка вопроса в данном случае и будет ответом.